# StackApps Captcha doesn't work: "Invalid domain for site key"

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

The [Captcha page](https://stackapps.com/captcha) on this site doesn't seem to be set up correctly, it shows an error message:

> ERROR for site owner:
> Invalid domain for site key

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Captcha wasn't configured correctly for Stack Apps on our end. The issue has been fixed.

Sorry for the inconvenience, and thanks for the report!